# Ruby - Best way to map objects into one array with fixed key

Tags: json, ruby

I try to merge some object into one array

I did output by

```
q = [["99","99","99"],["9"]]
o = [["b","1"],["c","3"],["d","1"],["c","30"]]

puts q.zip(o).map { |k,v| [*k,v] }.to_json

=> [["99",["b","1"]],["99",["c","3"]],["99",["d","1"]],["9",["c","30"]]]
```

i'm looking for best way to

```
[{"99"=>{"b"=>"1", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"1"}},{"9"=>{"c"=>"30"}]
```

Comment: Your "some array" is invalid.

Comment: yes, I'm still fresher, so I don't know to call this, but I print with this output and I try to beautify this output :(

Comment: No, it is not reproducible. Your initial array is invalid.

Comment: I have updated my question, for more my flow to do that output. Can you teach me how to make it smarter :(

Comment: Why do you have json?

Comment: Where does that `"10"` come from in the expected output?

Comment: Thank @sawa, because my output many many long, so I just cut a group for this question. I can solve this :(

Comment: Hi @Stefan, in next group, it just have same to group "9" :)

Comment: I expect the `"10"` is the reason for the downvote. You explained in a comment why it's there but your explanation is unsatisfactory because we don't know how `"q"` would change to incorprorate the `"10"`. In general, examples should only contain valid Ruby objects (no `"..."`, `"etc.."`, and so on). That way, all code suggested in answers can be run against the example and the return values obtained be compared with what the asker has stated to be the expected or desired result for the example.

Comment: Thank @CarySwoveland , because my output has many groups like the example I have mentioned. I will take care when sending a question :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [["9",["b","8"]],["9",["c","2"]],["9",["d","6"]]]

a.group_by(&:first).transform_values{|a| a.map(&:last).to_h}
# => {"9"=>{"b"=>"8", "c"=>"2", "d"=>"6"}}

a.group_by(&:first).transform_values{|a| a.map(&:last).to_h}.map{|k, v| {k => v}}
# => [{"9"=>{"b"=>"8", "c"=>"2", "d"=>"6"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?:

```
some_array = [["9",["b","8"]], ["9",["c","2"]], ["9",["d","6"]]]
some_hash = some_array.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = {} }) do |(k, (sub_key, sub_val)), hash|
  hash[k][sub_key] = sub_val
end

p some_hash

#=> {"9"=>{"b"=>"8", "c"=>"2", "d"=>"6"}}
```